Drupal 10, images upload to public folder but render from different folder giving error
I have a fresh Drupal 10.2 installed on my server. I created a content type with 2 media fields. originally, when uploading using media module, I can see the image in my content creation page. However it is pointing to
"/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/2024-04/437759296_2002667260129835_2566743114858732679_n.jpg?itok=2wtECZO7"

While the file is being uploaded to
/sites/default/files/2024-4/437759296_2002667260129835_2566743114858732679_n.jpg

So when the image is rendered, it point to the first URL provided which is wrong and doesn't exist. Unless, I change the view of the image from "Manage display" of the content type from render entity into thumbnail.
This only happens on this server, if I install the same copy in my local machine the images work on both the content view and content creation page.
I am not sure what file I should be checking to figure this out. I tried to tinker in setting.php but that did not work.
I am not sure where to start tinkering.
Attached are the images:

is your folder permission correctly set, it should be 777 for files folder

Yeah the folder permission is 777 for file.

it is possibly due to image styles present in your admin section ( /admin/config/media/image-styles ). You can change the field display settings to render directly rather than showing an image style ( medium or thumbnail )

looks like imagestyles are not created?

From Drupal it looks like its created. in media/image-styles I do have around 4 styles. However their directory is not there. If i go to my public folder I can't see "large" or "thumbnail".

@ViswanathPolaki, This was the default behavior. by default the media is using rendered entity. this wouldn't work. I have to change it into thumbnail or a specific image style before being able to use it.
